# No audio/sound while playing MKV with HTML5

Tags: php, html, audio, media, movie

So i need a web browser MKV player, because i will download (to a server) some films with PHP, but lot of films type are MKV file. After the downloading i will play this MKV file.
So i have a file. I can play the file with the browser (Chrome), but it haven't got audio.

This solution is good, because if I will download musics or pictures I will watch it with smart TVs, tablets and lots of thing. And of course, I think it will be fast, because the files are in the server and the scripts are loading the files from the server.

What is the problem?

Comment: mkv is a container. it can contain MANY different media types/codecs. your audio may be in a format which your browser can't handle.

Comment: And how can I know which audio type I have?